# How to write Rspec for APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code in my API file

```
    class TransactionStatus < Grape::API
        helpers ::PushAPIv1::NamedParams

        post '/transaction/status' do
          Rails.logger.warn "#{params.to_xml}"
             // some piece of code
        end
      end
```

I tried to write Rpsec for this condition but not getting any success in my coverage report. The Spec I tried to write is as below

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Transaction, type: :request do
  context 'check Transaction Status' do
    it 'should log an info message' do
      expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:warn).with("#{params.to_xml}")
    end

    it 'should raise Transaction Not Found Error if invalid transaction' do
        transaction = FactoryGirl.build(:transaction, state: 'processing', gateway_message: 'success', ref_code: '1qqqq1')
        p transaction.ref_code
        expect { Transaction.find_by_ref_code('q1111q').should eq transaction }.to raise_error()
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if what you're trying to achieve is coverage of your `POST /transaction/status` endpoint, then... you need to reach for the endpoint in your specs, which you're not doing at the moment.

```
it 'should log an info message' do
  expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:warn).with("#{params.to_xml}")
end
```

Here you expect Rails.logger to receive `warn` message. But you need to trigger something that should call `Rails.logger.warn` for the spec to pass.

```
it 'should raise Transaction Not Found Error if invalid transaction' do
  transaction = FactoryGirl.build(:transaction, state: 'processing', gateway_message: 'success', ref_code: '1qqqq1')
  expect { Transaction.find_by_ref_code('q1111q').should eq transaction }.to raise_error()
end
```

About this spec: you're mixing `expect` and `should` syntaxes in a manner that's hardly understandable. Plus you're just using ActiveRecord methods, and never call your actual API endpoint. That's why you don't get any code coverage.

---

In the end, what you should do to get proper coverage of your endpoint is actually calling it. This could be done in a `before :each` block for instance, or even in each of your spec, like this:

```
describe 'transaction/status' do
  before :each do
    post 'path/to/api/transaction/status'
    # post 'path/to/api/transaction/status', params: { some: params }
    # post 'path/to/api/transaction/status', headers: { some: headers }
  end

  it '...' do
    expect( response ).to ...
  end
end
```

You get the idea. You can check out [RSpec Rails 3.7 - Request specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) for more details and examples.

Comment: How do i reach POST /transaction/status endpoint,
 And as you said ‘trigger something that should call Rails.logger.warn’ can you please help hoe to achieve it

Comment: @GOLDYAGARWAL is your API working outside rspec? I thought so after answering your initial question, but I'm not so sure anymore. If it's not working even outside RSpec then it's a different matter, and your problem would be about setting up Grape to work in a Rails project. In that cas, Grape readme should give you all you need to setup the API inside your project : https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape